# Quick Sort partition

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

I am trying to use an algorithm from "Algorithms" by Sedgewick, however, in the book I am reading, it asks how would the algorithm partition an array with the following String items:

```
k        1    2     3     4          5          6      7       8        9
arr[k]   dog  cat   cow   elephant   goldfish   horse  tiger   giraffe  panda
```

Using the method call partition `(0, 8, "elephant")`.

Isn't the array already partitioned and sorted? If if someone could explain this to me I would be very grateful.

This the partition method he uses:

```
void partition(int L0, int R0, String p)
{
   L = L0;
   R = R0;
   while ( L <= R )
   {
       // left scan
       while ( lt(arr[L], p) )
       {
         comps = comps + 1;
         L = L + 1;
        }
       comps = comps + 1; 
       // right_scan
       while ( lt(p, arr[R]) )
       {
         comps = comps + 1;
         R = R - 1;
       }
       comps = comps + 1;  
       if ( L <= R )
       {
           exchange(L,R);
           exchs = exchs + 1;
           L = L + 1;
           R = R - 1;
        }
    }
} // partition
```

Comment: that partition will do nothing, because c and d come before e, and g,h,t,p come after e

Comment: Sorry I added the code under the question.

Comment: Did you step through the code / run it to see what will happen / happens? If so, you know what will happen, so I'm not sure what needs explaining. And would it really be unbelievable that nothing much will happen in some cases? Or that someone will ask what will happen in such a case?

Comment: Yes I worked through it and nothing happens. I just wasn't sure why the author of the book would ask the question if nothing happens, I thought I might be missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Array is not sorted by values (arr[k]). It needs to be sorted by values, not indices